# Ruby: why are inputs passed to send() being wrapped in a Hash?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm using the send() method in Ruby to invoke a method I've defined. The method takes an `OpenStruct`.

Here's a snippet showing how I invoke my method using `send`:

```
my_open_struct = OpenStruct.new(foo: "foo")

result = @my_object.send(
            :my_method_that_takes_an_openstruct,
            name_of_openstruct_param: my_open_struct)
```

The problem is that inside `my_method_that_takes_an_openstruct` the `OpenStruct` param is getting wrapped in a `Hash`, resulting in logging output like this:

```
Just before calling send #<OpenStruct foo="foo">
Inside my_method_that_takes_an_openstruct: {:name_of_openstruct_param=>#<OpenStruct foo="foo">}
```

Why is this happening, and how can I prevent this wrapping behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming `my_method` looks something like this

```
class Foo
  def my_method(arg)
    puts "#{arg}"
  end
end
```

If you're coming from a Python background, you might think we can call `my_method` as either `foo.my_method(1)` or `foo.my_method(arg: 1)`. But this isn't how it works in Ruby. In Ruby, arguments are *either* named or positional. To make an argument named, we put a colon after it.

```
class Foo
  def my_method(arg:)
    puts "#{arg}"
  end
end
```

Now we can do `Foo.new.my_method(arg: 1)` or `Foo.new.send(:my_method, arg: 1)`, but it's *incorrect* to do `Foo.new.my_method(1)`.

The reason you're getting a hash is a compatibility trick. In old versions of Ruby, before we had named arguments, the convention was to take a single hash argument at the end

```
def foo(a, b, opts)
  ...
end
```

and then the following two calls would be equivalent (the former being syntax sugar for the latter)

```
foo(1, 2, foo: "bar", bar: "baz")
foo(1, 2, {foo: "bar", bar: "baz"})
```

Basically, if any named-looking arguments appeared in an argument list, they'd get converted to a single hash and passed as the final argument to the function.

This behavior is [deprecated](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/25/ruby-2-7-0-released/) as of Ruby 2.7 and [removed](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14183) in Ruby 3.0. The correct convention now is to take explicit named arguments, and recent versions of Ruby support the double splat `**` operator for converting a hash *into* named arguments, similar to the Python operator with the same name.